# Create context variable for console application

Tags: c#

I have an application that runs both as a console and as a windows service. It processes files and can handle several files at once with threading. Every now and then it fetches a file that is "tagged" as a testfile.

The flow is something like this:

- Read file
- Determine if test
- Validate file
- Save contents of file into db
- Move file
- Report to other service about the file.

All the steps need to know if the file is a testfile or not, but all the steps don't have access to the file per say.

Instead of passing a `bool isTest` parameter to every method I would like to create a context variable that is applicable to just that file and that particular execution (specific for the stack). Somewhat similiar to `OperationContext` in WCF. I would use `ThreadStatic` but I have a lot of `async` `await`, and I'm afraid that the thread can be re-used by another context.

Is there a way to keep a variable in a sort of session or context that is bound to a specific execution? Something like this (just example code):

```
var isTest = true;
var fileProcessor = new FileProcessor(); // It's injected, but just an example.
using(ContextFactory.CreateContext(isTest))
{
    // Process file. 
    // All methods in this stack should be able to determine if it's a testfile or not.
    fileProcessor.ProcessFile(myFilePath);
}


public class FileProcessor
{
    public void ProcessFile(string fileName)
    {
        // Should be able to determine if it's a test or not.
        var isTest = ContextFactory.IsTest()

       // This method will call other classes and other methods in a long chain.
    }
}
```

I'm using Unity for IoC and C# 4.5.